# How to load environment variables into ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a ruby gem which loads config variables from a yaml file. Currently it is being parsed with `YAML.load_file`. In rails it is possible to parse ruby in a yaml file like the following (e.g. settings.yaml):

```
key: <%= ENV["key"] || "default value" %>
```

What is the best way to produce a similar result in a ruby gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just [ERB](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html), so you can run your file through ERB before parsing it with YAML:

```
YAML.load(ERB.new(File.read(your_file_path)).result)
```